# Convert multiple columns in desktop to 2 columns in mobile view

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to convert 3 columns in desktop view to 2 columns in mobile view.
 I tried to use different column widths but I could  get 1 column  .  How can I get 2 columns in mobile view ?

```
    <HTML>

     <HEAD>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />

     <style>

    .col  {
     border: 1px solid #000000;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30%;     
       height: 120px;
        text-align: center;   
      margin-left:35px;    
     margin-right:1px;
       }


      /*-------------------mobile-------------------*/

      @media screen and (max-width:900px) 

     .col {
     width: 50%;
       }        
         }
        </style>
           </HEAD>
          <BODY >

          <div class="row">           

            <div class="col">                <!--  1 -->    
             cell 1 </div>  

     <div class="col">               <!--  2  -->
             cell 2         </div>     

          <div class="col">                       <!--    3  -->
          cell 3  </div>        

          </div>                              
               </BODY>
               </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the margins on the .col class
this makes the .col element 50% + both margins.

You should either remove the margins, or lower the percentage.

You can use the CSS3 function CALC(), to calculate the exact width. 
More information about calc here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc